# Cannot maven build spring boot application with elastic search

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to use elastic search in my spring boot application. The project runs fine when I run it with the IDE, i.e. with the embedded tomcat server of spring boot application.
When I try to run "mvn clean install" to package it for deployment,the build prompts me with

`NoClassDefFoundError` Exception

Here lies my stack trace that caused the problem

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticService' defined in file [/home/abiral/apps/elastic-project/target/classes/com/elastic/project/elasticproject/elastic/ElasticService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.elastic.project.elasticproject.elastic.ElasticService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/script/ScriptEngine
```

My Pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>






</dependencies>
```

Has anybody faced this issue before?
I googled, but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.
Please suggest me a solution.

`mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] com.elastic.project:elastic-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-     web:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.15.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.7.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:5.6.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:6.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:securesm:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.4.0-1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:jar:5.6.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.27.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.locationtech.spatial4j:spatial4j:jar:0.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:reindex-client:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:percolator-client:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:6.3.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Can you run `mvn dependency:tree` on your project?

Comment: I edited my question with the tree, please have a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java an idea about noclassdeffounderror.

Comment: You have a dependency conflict. Since you include `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` you shouldn't also have a dependency on `org.elasticsearch.client`. `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` depends on `spring-data-elasticsearch` which in turn imports the `org.elasticsearch` libraries. If you want ES 6.3.2 you need to use Spring Boot v2.1.0.M2.

Comment: When i removed `org.elasticsearch.client`  the build prompted with
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin
`

Comment: I tried adding the Netty3plugin from maven and removed the client dependency it seems to work now. Thank you.